# I am having trouble fitting this curve - Does anyone know what a good equation to fit could be?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, data-analysis

I have the following plot:

[image]

It represents the production of electricity of a turbine as a function of flow.

I am trying to fit a curve to it. The best I got was:

```
Production = -1591.5 * Flow + 38141.6 * Flow/sqrt(Flow)
```

But the fit is not that good when I plot the fitted and the real values on the same plot, especially not for really small or big values of flows.

Can anyone recommend me a better way to fit my production ?

[image]

Here is the data:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/hwf1gk4x3xbidee/table.csv?dl=0

Comment: Could you please post a table of values? I'm not surprised the function you have there didn't do very well; there's no way it could capture the behavior of decreasing, and possibly leveling out.

Comment: I would choose another function. Why have you chosen $y=a \cdot  x+b \cdot  \frac{x}{\sqrt x} (=\sqrt x)$?

Comment: I added the data via dropbox.

I chose the function randomly honestly

Comment: @meteoeliot: Great, thanks! As a side comment: semicolons are extremely rare as delimiters in csv files. I'd recommend commas, or better yet, tabs.

Comment: @meteoeliot You can try the limited growth function or the logistic growth function, see [here](http://www.math.umd.edu/~tjp/131%2011.1-2%20supplement%20logistic%20growth.pdf) .

Comment: I had a look at your data and have a few questions. First, what do you mean with "Production of electricity" ? Is it the output in Watts ? What is flowing through the turbine ? (Water, gas, air, ...) What is the units of this "flow" ? cubic metres per second ? What do you know about the physics, which are relevant for the production rate ? The data point with the very large flow seems to be exceptional. Can it be taken into account ? It would have great influence on the details of the modeling for leveling-off.

Comment: Your data seem to be collected over a period of about ten years. Is there more known about the circumstances ? For example, there seems to be a drop in productivity in 2017. The points below 50000 ... well ... Watts (?) ... seem to stem from this year. Is it possible that the system did not work properly then ? Maybe one has to disregard the data from this period then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the function does indeed level out to a constant, then it looks like you have two decaying functions that are overlapping plus an additive constant.  One of the functions decays more quickly, and one decays more slowly.  For example:

- $$
  f(x)= C + \frac{A}{x} + \frac{B}{x^2}
  $$
  Here's [a plot of this function with $C = 1, B = -1, A = 3$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Graph+of+-1%2Fx%5E2%2B3%2Fx+%2B+1+from+x%3D0+to+5).
- $$ f(x) = C + A e^{-\alpha x} + B e^{-\beta x} $$
  Here's [a plot of this function with $C = 1, A = 3, B = -4, \alpha = 1, \beta = 2$.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Graph+of+1+%2B+3+e%5E(-x)+-+4+e%5E(-2x)+from+x+%3D+0+to+5)

Unfortunately, I was unable to to download your data into my preferred curve-fitting software, but hopefully you can figure out how to apply these functions on your own.  Note that the second of these functions is *not* a "linear" regression, since the free parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$ do not enter into the function linearly.

Comment: If you do a search-and-replace in the data file, you can replace the semicolons with commas or tabs, and then it might import easier. Your graphs look a lot better than mine, particularly with respect to extrapolation to high flows. I'd be extremely interested to see your $R^2$ values and a residual plot; could you please try to get to that point?

Comment: I guess your first suggestion, which diverges for $x \rightarrow 0$, is not well suited because one can expect the production to go to zero for zero flow. It would be interesting to know more about the physical process behind the data, in order to restrict the space of possible functions.

Comment: I used the function with the exponential and used C = 0. It was har to find starting values for the nlsLM function in R I used but it still turned out more or less ok. Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

You can go for broke on questions like this. The fact is, there's no one function that's going to be "the best". There are measures of the goodness of fit, such as the coefficient of determination, $R^2$; it's useful, but not the end-all, be-all. You should always plot your residuals. For example, in Excel, I found that a fourth-order polynomial wasn't too awful bad:
$$\operatorname{prod}=-0.0029\operatorname{flow}^4+1.2195\operatorname{flow}^3
-175.89\operatorname{flow}^2+9889.9\operatorname{flow}+7797.1$$
with $R^2=0.4024.$ An $R^2$ closer to $1$ would be better, certainly, but this function captures the basic shape, I think. Now if you plot the residuals, you're looking to make sure there's no definite pattern (thus indicating your model is leaving something out). I've got the basic plot plus the residuals shown here:

[image: Fit and Residuals]

You can see that there's definitely a pattern, mostly corresponding to the small cluster of points originally located near $\operatorname{flow}=17,\;\operatorname{prod}=25000.$

So you could certainly do better than this. But this will hopefully get you started. What you're doing is called linear regression, but a proviso: it's called linear even if you're fitting odd shapes like polynomials or exponentials to your data. It's linear because the coefficients show up in a linear fashion.